# Should I use cursors in my SQL procedure?

Tags: mysql, cursor

I have a table that contains computer login and logoff events.  Each row is a separate event with a timestamp, machine name, login or logoff event code and other details.  I need to create a SQL procedure that goes through this table and locates corresponding login and logoff event and insert new rows into another table that contain the machine name, login time, logout time and duration time.

So, should I use a cursor to do this or is there a better way to go about this?  The database is pretty huge so efficiency is certainly a concern.  Any suggested pseudo code would be great as well.

[edit : pulled from comment]

Source table:

```
History (
      mc_id
    , hs_opcode
    , hs_time
)
```

Existing data interpretation:

```
Login_Event  = unique mc_id, hs_opcode = 1, and hs_time is the timestamp
Logout_Event = unique mc_id, hs_opcode = 2, and hs_time is the timestamp
```

Comment: Let me see if I can be clearer.  I have a table called History with columns mc_id, hs_opcode, and hs_time.  For a login event there will be a unique mc_id, hs_opcode = 1, and hs_time is the timestamp.  On a logout event; unique mc_id, hs_opcode = 2, and hs_time is the timestamp.  I need to process each login event in the entire table and search for its corresponding logout event.  So for the logout event, it will be the next logout record for that machine after the login event; mc_id will be equal, hs_opcode = 2, and timestamp will be greater.  Then I will insert this into new table.

Comment: The answer to your question is no, you shouldn't have to use cursors for this. In fact, using a cursor would likely be much slower than the set-based solution proposed below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your query will be simpler (and faster) if you can order the data in such a way that you don't need a complex subquery to pair up the rows. Since MySQL doesn't support CTE to do this on-the-fly, you'll need to create a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE history_ordered (
  seq INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  hs_id INT,
  mc_id VARCHAR(255),
  mc_loggedinuser VARCHAR(255),
  hs_time DATETIME,
  hs_opcode INT
);
```

Then, pull and sort from your original table into the new table:

```
INSERT INTO history_ordered (
  hs_id, mc_id, mc_loggedinuser,
  hs_time, hs_opcode)
SELECT
  hs_id, mc_id, mc_loggedinuser,
  hs_time, hs_opcode
FROM history ORDER BY mc_id, hs_time;
```

You can now use this query to correlate the data:

```
SELECT li.mc_id,
       li.mc_loggedinuser,
       li.hs_time as login_time,
       lo.hs_time as logout_time
FROM   history_ordered AS li
JOIN   history_ordered AS lo
  ON   lo.seq = li.seq + 1
   AND li.hs_opcode = 1;
```

For future inserts, you can use a trigger like below to keep your duration table updated automatically:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `match_login` AFTER INSERT ON `history`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF NEW.hs_opcode = 2 THEN
  DECLARE _user VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE _login DATETIME;
  SELECT mc_loggedinuser, hs_time FROM history
  WHERE hs_time = (
   SELECT MAX(hs_time) FROM history
   WHERE hs_opcode = 1
   AND mc_id = NEW.mc_id
  ) INTO _user, _login;
  INSERT INTO login_duration
  SET machine = NEW.mc_id,
  logout = NEW.hs_time,
  user = _user,
  login = _login;
 END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: +1 --- execution time should also be faster than having a subquery like in my post

Answer (score 2):

```sql
CREATE TABLE dummy (fields you'll select data into, + additional fields as needed)

INSERT INTO dummy (columns from your source)
SELECT * FROM <all the tables where you need data for your target data set>

UPDATE dummy SET col1 = CASE WHEN this = this THEN that, etc

INSERT INTO targetTable
SELECT all columns FROM dummy
```

Without any code that you're working on.. it'll be hard to see if this approach will be any useful.. There may be some instances when you really need to loop through things.. and some instances when this approach can be used instead..

[EDIT: based on poster's comment]

Can you try executing this and see if you get the desired results?

```sql
INSERT INTO <your_target_table_here_with_the_three_columns_required>
SELECT li.mc_id, li.hs_time AS login_time, lo.hs_time AS logout_time
FROM
    history AS li
    INNER JOIN history AS lo
        ON li.mc_id = lo.mc_id
            AND li.hs_opcode = 1
            AND lo.hs_opcode = 2
            AND lo.hs_time = (
                SELECT min(hs_time) AS hs_time 
                FROM history 
                WHERE hs_time > li.hs_time 
                AND mc_id = li.mc_id
            )
```

Comment: Do those additional details help?

Comment: I believe it works! However I tried it on a rather small subset of all of the records; about 3000 records and it took a while to run.  The full database is over 2 million records.  I dont imagine this approach would work for a database that size.  Any other ideas?

Comment: What indexes do you have in place?

Comment: Currently none.  What would you suggest?

Comment: Is it too late to restructure your table? with only three columns, it doesn't seem likely that we'll be able to put a decent index. `mc_id` is repeating, but wait.. are these login and logout times values that overlap days? like a login can be 11:50PM today then logout be 7AM tomorrow? And are you processing this data on a daily basis?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5895/discussion-between-nonym-and-jomille)